# How to write nested functions in UrlHelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, urlhelper

I'm writting a UrlHelper and now I need to write a nested function because for example I have page Articles which is accessed for everyone and I have separate Articles in Admin panel.
First have link: /Articles and next /Admin/Articles.

So I want to use UrlHelper like this:

*In public page:*

```
Url.Articles()
```

*In admin page:*

```
Url.Admin.Article()
```

Please tell me how I can achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement `Url.Admin().Article()` by writing an `Admin()` extension method for the UrlHelper that returns an instance of some class with the Article() method.

However, C# does not support extension properties so the `Url.Admin.Article()` nested method is not possible without modifying ASP MVC source code.